# Csv doesn't generate when it

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

It doesn't generate.

when it did, the file was blank.

```
    import csv
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
for i in range(3):
        r = requests.get('https://www.nairaland.com/search/afonja/0/0/0/{}'.format(i))
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        occurrences = len(soup.select('.highlight')) #if soup.select_one('.highlight') else 
    z=[occurrences]
    with open('z.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow([z])
```

Update: someone has solved it. It was clear to that user.

Comment: What does `total` do? `z` ends up being `[46]` for me now. Is this what you want? Do you have your permissions set correctly? Your code works for me.

Comment: Its suppose to show three values for the range. Total isn't a part of it, i've edited it

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: You are replacing the file on each iteration, it overwrites the file three times with different values instead of writing three values to the same file. But a proper answer would require a proper question where you explain what you actually want.

Comment: i want all values gotten from the range to show on the csv file. There are supposed to be 3 values that appear on the csv.

Comment: Open the file once at the beginning. Then call `writer.writerow` in the loop.

Comment: Is it supposed to be one row with 3 fields, or 3 rows with one field?

Comment: Please fix the code indentation in the question to match your actual code.

Comment: @Barmar  3 fields one row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to collect all the occurrence values into a list, not overwrite the list each time through the loop. After the loop, write the list to the CSV file.

And since `z` is already a list, you don't need to write `[z]` when writing it to the file.

```
import csv
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
z = []
for i in range(3):
    r = requests.get('https://www.nairaland.com/search/afonja/0/0/0/{}'.format(i))
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    occurrences = len(soup.select('.highlight'))
    z.append(occurrences)
with open('z.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow(z)
```

Comment: Or you could open when you start, and wrnte things by and by as you collect them.

Comment: That won't work, since they'll be written on separate lines. He wants one line with fields for each value.

Comment: Thanks,it worked